# Multiple virtual hosts support for apache with scgi quixote backend for some host

Tags: python, apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-python

I'm trying to add a domain with [quixote](http://quixote.ca/) as its backend. I searched google and found that there are servaral choices to glue quixote and apache together.  I chose scgi because it seems like the choice with the best performace.

So, I installed mod_python and scgi_apache, but got stuck with the config. I found a tutorial with google that said the usual scgi configuration for apache is:

```
SCGIMount / 127.0.0.1:3000
```

which only redirects some requests with the url posfix with the root "/" to the quixote request handler, so when I tried to redirect some domain requests to it:

```
SCGIMount www.mydomain.com 127.0.0.1:3000
```

it didn't work and just directed to the page of my default host.

Does anyone have a solution or advice on this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

By the way, anyone with reputation over 1500 please add "quixote" as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

after study, I finally figured out how to make certain host to support quixote while keep other hosts out. Actually, we can add the

```
SCGIMount / 127.0.0.1:3000
```

into some virtual hsot configuration file in the httpd-vhost.conf file. e.g., here is my configuration:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin david@itbeing.com
   DocumentRoot "/Users/itbeing/Projects/www/itbeing.com"
   ServerName www.itbeing.com
   ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
   CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" com$
   #setup a location to be servered by an SCGI server process.
   SCGIMount /  127.0.0.1:3000
   </VirtualHost>
```

That is it. Hopefully this would help to else who have the same similar question.